# Super current and critical current

Tags: solid-state-physics, superconductivity

Is there any difference between critical current and super current in superconductivity?

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon of [supercurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercurrent), a current that flows indefinitely long without any voltage applied, across a device known as a Josephson junction (JJ), which consists of two or more [superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity) coupled by a weak link. The weak link can consist of a thin insulating barrier (known as a [superconductor–insulator–superconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_tunnel_junction) junction, or S-I-S), a short section of non-superconducting metal (S-N-S), or a physical constriction that weakens the superconductivity at the point of contact (S-s-S).

---

[Critical current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_field) – the maximum electric current density that a given superconducting material can carry, before switching into the normal state.

In case you are looking for some rigorous explanation :

Christopher L. Henley. "Lecture 6.4 - Supercurrent and critical currents". [States in Solids](https://web.archive.org/web/20111222125818/http://people.ccmr.cornell.edu/%7Eclh/BT-GL/6.4.pdf)

[Electrodynamics of Superconductors: Weakly Coupled](https://doi.org/10.1016/B0-08-043152-6/00460-5)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!